# How do I move a list item to the owner's recycling bin?

Tags: powershell

I have a need to run a PowerShell script against a list that deletes items older than 15 days. I have the script written, as well as user notifications, however I am puzzled as to how I can recycle the item as the owner of the document.

This is simplified for the sake of the question, but this is the basic operation going on.

```
$fileage = 15
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$query.RowLimit = 2000;
$query.Query = '<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Occurred" /></OrderBy><Where><Lt><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-' + $fileAge + '" /></Value></Lt></Where>'
$listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
ForEach($file in $listItems){$item.Recycle()}
```

Now all the items in that list end up in the recycling bin of the *user* I ran the command under. Is it possible to take those files and move them into a specific user's bin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to impersonate the user, but will involve opening up a web object for each specific user.

```
$user=$web.AllUsers.GetByID(28)
$token = $user.UserToken;
$impWebObj= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($web.Url, $token);
$imperWeb = $impWebObj.OpenWeb();
$list = $imperWeb.Lists["SPLISTNAME"]
$fileage = 15
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$query.RowLimit = 2000;
$query.Query = '<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Occurred" /></OrderBy><Where><Lt><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-' + $fileAge + '" /></Value></Lt></Where>'
$listitems = $list.GetItems($query)
ForEach($file in $listItems){
  $item = list.GetItemsByID($file.ID)
  $item.Recycle()

}
$imperWeb.Dispose()
$impWebObj.Dispose()
```

There may be a less taxing way of doing this, but that's the idea I came up with.

Source: http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.com/2011/04/powershell-and-sharepoint-impersonation.html

EDIT: If it's a **specific** user, you can get the user by ID...